# Search Order List in Admin By Order Status

Tags: wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuzQc.png)

I want to search order list by order status in Shop Order Page.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'shipping_awb_searchable_field', 10, 1 );
function shipping_awb_searchable_field($meta_keys){
    $meta_keys[] = '_billing_phone';
    $meta_keys[] = '_order_total';

    return $meta_keys;
}
```

I Use this code for searching in order list

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'shipping_awb_searchable_field', 10, 1 );
function shipping_awb_searchable_field($meta_keys){
    $meta_keys[] = 'blue_dart_awb';
    $meta_keys[] = '_billing_phone';
  $meta_keys[] = '_order_total';

    return $meta_keys;
}

Comment: Please describe your questions, what is your question?